# Jpa eclipselink bug when try persist collection by another entity

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

Hello i have got one entity which contains collection of object:

```
@Entity
public class ResourceType{
   @Id
   public Integer id;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "resourcesTypes")
  private Set<Resource> resources = new HashSet<>();

}
```

As you see this entity contains collection of Resource

```
@Entity
public class Resource{

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "RESOURCE_TYPE_CROSS", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "RESOURCE_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "RESOURCE_TYPE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") })
    private List<ResourceType> resourcesTypes = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

So i guess if i get all resourceTypes with all resources this collection is in local cache.

But if i try persist resource :

```
    @Override
    public ResourcesDTO createResource(ResourcesDTO resource) throws CreateResourceException {

    if (resource.getResourcesTypes().isEmpty()) {
        throw new CreateResourceException("Can not create resouce " + resource.getName()
                + " none resource types is set");                                      
    resourceDAO.create(map(resource));      

    log.debug("Created resource: " + r);
    resource.setId(r.getId());

    return resource

    }
```

If i perssist Resource with ResourcesTypes and next i will get all ResourceTypes entity manager do not found new Resources. But in my cross table resource_type_cross everything is ok. i will try to do something like that after create new resource:

```
for(ResourceType rt : resource.getResourceTypes()){
    em.refresh(rt);
}
```

But its not working properly. After i will restart server everything is fine. But why entity manager do not refresh resource type ??

This is what i use to read all ResourceTypes:

```
public ResourceType getAllResourceTypes(){
    em.createQuery("Select n from Resource n left join fetch n.children"); 
    return em.find(ResourceType.class, 0); //0 - ROOT
```

}

as follow article : http://www.tikalk.com/java/load-tree-jpa-and-hibernate

**The Main question is that :**
create or update entity by one side do not update another, so in my case i create and update resource type by resource entity, but i am using resouce type to get all resource.

Answer (score 2):

First, there is a problem with your ManyToMany mappings.  You have made both sides unidirectional accessing the same join table instead of bidirectional.  One side should control the mapping, with the other set to mappedby the owning side.

Second, have you flushed or committed the changes when you refresh ResourceTypes?  It is probably better to maintain both sides by setting the reference in code rather than query to refresh each and every ResourceType

Comment: OK so i try to add @ManyToMany(mappedBy="resouces")
private Set<ResourceType> resourcesTypes = new HashSet<>(); but its not working ?

Comment: What isn't working, and did you remove the JoinTable annotation?  It won't solve your current problem, but it does need to be corrected or you will run into issues.  Refresh will work if the data is in the database when it is called.  Try turning on EclipseLink logging to see where and when the statements are written out and the refresh is occurring. http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging

Comment: I am edit my question as you suggest. Why if i correctly persist resouce with resouceTypes , and next i will get all resouce types with resources so this query do not return that just created resource entity ? i do not understand that .. :/ but if i restart glassfish everything is fine ...

Comment: JPA does not maintain relationships for you.  Entities are treated as regular java objects, so if you do not maintain both sides of bidirectional relationships, the other side will remain as you left it until the entity is refreshed.  Restarting the server clears the cache, which is the same as refreshing the entity in question.  What I thought you were looking at is why refresh wasn't pulling the changes from the relation table.  Is that an issue?

Comment: the point is why em do not refresh ResourceTypes ?
i am edit my question and add query which i am using to get all ResoureType with children....

Comment: I don't really understand the code you have posted.  You call create query, but do not use the created query object and instead call em.find with a 0 pk.  Bottom line is you must maintain both sides of relationships in JPA as you would with any java object.  If refresh is not working, check the logs and transactional boundaries to figure out why - chances are your data isn't there yet.